# Spring Feed Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, jdom-2, rome

i work with spring and spring-integration. I need get rss stream and write (right now is file). This is my application config for spring:

```
<int:channel id="rssFeedChannel">
        <int:queue capacity="40"/>
    </int:channel>

    <file:outbound-channel-adapter id="file" mode="APPEND" charset="UTF-8" directory="/tmp/si" filename-generator-expression="'SpringBlog'"/>

    <feed:inbound-channel-adapter id="news" channel="rssFeedChannel" url="https://spring.io/blog.atom">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>
    </feed:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:transformer input-channel="rssFeedChannel" expression="payload.title + ' @ ' + payload.link + '#{systemProperties['line.separator']}'" output-channel="file"/>
```

I run the application and get exceptions:

```
SEVERE: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.rometools.rome.io.WireFeedInput.createSAXBuilder(WireFeedInput.java:306)...
```

---

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This parser does not support specification "null" version "null"
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.setSchema(SAXParserFactory.java:419)
at org.jdom2.input.sax.XMLReaders.<init>(XMLReaders.java:122)
at org.jdom2.input.sax.XMLReaders.<clinit>(XMLReaders.java:95)
... 32 more


Jul 22, 2015 1:54:08 AM org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler handleMessageInternal
SEVERE: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jdom2.input.sax.XMLReaders
```

my pom.xml:

```
  <properties>
        <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.integration.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.7.Final</hibernate.version>
        <junit-version>4.11</junit-version>
        <servlet-api-version>3.1.0</servlet-api-version>
        <jsp-version>2.1</jsp-version>
        <jstl-version>1.2</jstl-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>rome</groupId>
            <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>rome</groupId>
            <artifactId>rome-fetcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-feed</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Full stacktrace:

```
Jul 22, 2015 11:48:57 PM org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler handleMessageInternal
SEVERE: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jdom2.input.sax.XMLReaders
    at com.rometools.rome.io.WireFeedInput.createSAXBuilder(WireFeedInput.java:306)
    at com.rometools.rome.io.WireFeedInput.build(WireFeedInput.java:207)
    at com.rometools.rome.io.SyndFeedInput.build(SyndFeedInput.java:133)
    at com.rometools.fetcher.impl.HttpURLFeedFetcher.readSyndFeedFromStream(HttpURLFeedFetcher.java:300)
    at com.rometools.fetcher.impl.HttpURLFeedFetcher.getSyndFeedFromStream(HttpURLFeedFetcher.java:306)
    at com.rometools.fetcher.impl.HttpURLFeedFetcher.resetFeedInfo(HttpURLFeedFetcher.java:217)
    at com.rometools.fetcher.impl.HttpURLFeedFetcher.retrieveAndCacheFeed(HttpURLFeedFetcher.java:188)
    at com.rometools.fetcher.impl.HttpURLFeedFetcher.retrieveFeed(HttpURLFeedFetcher.java:140)
    at com.rometools.fetcher.impl.HttpURLFeedFetcher.retrieveFeed(HttpURLFeedFetcher.java:99)
    at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.getFeed(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:204)
    at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.populateEntryList(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:182)
    at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.doReceive(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.receive(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:122)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:144)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:192)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:298)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:292)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh stop
Jul 22, 2015 11:49:02 PM org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler handleMessageInternal
SEVERE: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jdom2.input.sax.XMLReaders
    at com.rometools.rome.io.WireFeedInput.createSAXBuilder(WireFeedInput.java:306)
    at com.rometools.rome.io.WireFeedInput.build(WireFeedInput.java:207)
    at com.rometools.rome.io.SyndFeedInput.build(SyndFeedInput.java:133)
    at com.rometools.fetcher.impl.HttpURLFeedFetcher.readSyndFeedFromStream(HttpURLFeedFetcher.java:300)
    at com.rometools.fetcher.impl.HttpURLFeedFetcher.getSyndFeedFromStream(HttpURLFeedFetcher.java:306)
    at com.rometools.fetcher.impl.HttpURLFeedFetcher.resetFeedInfo(HttpURLFeedFetcher.java:217)
    at com.rometools.fetcher.impl.HttpURLFeedFetcher.retrieveAndCacheFeed(HttpURLFeedFetcher.java:188)
    at com.rometools.fetcher.impl.HttpURLFeedFetcher.retrieveFeed(HttpURLFeedFetcher.java:140)
    at com.rometools.fetcher.impl.HttpURLFeedFetcher.retrieveFeed(HttpURLFeedFetcher.java:99)
    at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.getFeed(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:204)
    at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.populateEntryList(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:182)
    at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.doReceive(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.receive(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:122)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:144)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:192)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:298)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:292)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How fix this?

Answer (score 1):

According to you logs:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jdom2.input.sax.XMLReaders

it looks like you don't use any dependency management tool for your project. Hence you lose `jdom` jar in your target classpath.

I tell that because of:

```
\--- com.rometools:rome-fetcher:1.5.0
     +--- com.rometools:rome:1.5.0
     |    +--- com.rometools:rome-utils:1.5.0
     |    +--- org.jdom:jdom:2.0.2
     |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7 -> 1.7.10
```

As dependency tree for `spring-integration-feed`.

Hope this picture will help you to figure out your issue.

Comment: I add application pom.xml, look please.

Comment: Looks good. But that is POM for your project. Does your  Tomcat has all those deps? Or do you include them to your WEB-INF/lib ? As I guess `SEVERE` isn't standard log level, so some application server overwrites our Apache commons to that one at runtime.

Comment: Good (or bad :-)). Share, please, `cause` for that `NoClassDefFoundError`. Seems for me that isn't the whole StackTrace..

Comment: All stacktrace in the quastion

Comment: Fix pom.xml. I add `<dependency>
            <groupId>rome</groupId>
            <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rometools</groupId>
            <artifactId>rome-utils</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rometools</groupId>
            <artifactId>rome-fetcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>`